# Android Studio gradle doesn't sync if edit other gradle files except build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

To make Android Studio configuration simply, I move all declaration of version name, version code, change logs into `versions.gradle`. For example

```
ext {
    def versionMajor = 0
    def versionMinor = 9
    def versionPatch = 5
    def buildNumber = 95
    def buildName = "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"    
    appVersion = [
            versionCode: buildNumber,
            versionName: buildName
    ]
}
```

Then, in `build.gradle` of project level, include it:

`apply from: "versions.gradle"`

But, if I edit `versions.gradle` (change version number), the whole project doesn't automatically sync or even show a warning message ask to sync. I must manually sync Gradle. Moreover, if my co-worker pulls `versions.gradle` to his repo, Gradle sync doesn't run in his side. Or, he must know there is Gradle changes, then manually sync.

It seems Android Studio only automatically sync if `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` are changed. Is there any way to force Gradle sync if any change was made in `*.gradle`?

I'm using Android Studio 1.5 with Gradle 2.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug. I've filed https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196727 to track this.

Answer (score 1):

Sync button should do what you ask for!!

Or Exiting Android Studio and opening the project again should try to sync gradle

Comment: Thanks. I know should sync Gradle in my side. But if my co-worker pulls `versions.gradle`, it doesn't automatically sync Gradle. Or I must tell him to sync manually.